# How to properly reduce a set of TMs to the halting problem?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem

Consider a standard enumeration of Turing machines ($T_0, T_1, T_2$, ...).

Then, let language A be defined as $A = \{n \in\mathbb N | T_n(\lambda) \downarrow\}$.

I need to reduce it to the halting problem (let's call it $K$). So, I want $K \leq_m A$ (mapping reduction).

I know that mapping reduction is based on the idea that $w \in K$ if and only if $f(w) \in A$. Also, $f(w)$ must be computable. I don't know how to reduce properly.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Is $A$ the set of all Turing machines? Is it the set of Turing machines that always halt? Is it the set of Turing machines that halt when given themselves as input? It sounds like the first, but that's a decidable set. You can trivially reduce it to anything.

Comment: Can you show me how to formally reduce it to the halting problem set? I looked at some proofs online, but always stuck at proving that the function f(w) will be computable to correctly reduce the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: You say you want to reduce $A$ to $K$, then you write $K \leq_m A$, which instead mentions reducing $K$ to $A$, then you finally mention the definition, which is reducing $A$ to $K$ one again. Which direction are you trying to prove?

Comment: Sorry again I started learning mapping reduction. I definitely meant K<A. So, reducing K to A. Thanks for editing.

Comment: $K\le_m A$ means $w\in K$ if and only if $f(w)\in A$.

Comment: Thanks! I realized how horribly I asked this question. I will make sure that I write questions properly.

Comment: What do the down arrow and the $\lambda$ mean? Also you're still saying you want to reduce *to* the halting problem $K$, but you write that you want $K \leq_m A$.